# X Error of failed request: BadMatch

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, nvidia, glut

I'm trying to execute some "hello world" opengl code:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void displayCall() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    ... Some more code here
    glutSwapBuffers();
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(300, 200);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 2);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello World!");
    glutDisplayFunc(displayCall);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

As a result I get:

```
  X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  128 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
fghCreateNewContext() at freeglut_window.c:737 0x7ffff7bbaa81   
fgOpenWindow() at freeglut_window.c:878 0x7ffff7bbb2fb  
fgCreateWindow() at freeglut_structure.c:106 0x7ffff7bb9d86 
glutCreateWindow() at freeglut_window.c:1,183 0x7ffff7bbb4f2    
main() at AlphaTest.cpp:51 0x4007df
```

Here is the last piece of code, after witch the program crashes:

```
createContextAttribs = 
  (CreateContextAttribsProc) fghGetProcAddress("glXCreateContextAttribsARB" );
if ( createContextAttribs == NULL ) {
    fgError( "glXCreateContextAttribsARB not found" );
}
context = createContextAttribs( dpy, config, share_list, direct, attributes );
```

"glXCreateContextAttribsARB" address is obtained successfully, but the program crashes on its invocation.

If I specify OpenGL version less than 4.2 in "glutInitContextVersion()" program runs without errors.

Here is my glxinfo's OpelGL version:

```
OpenGL version string: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 285.05.09
```

I would be very appreciate any further ideas.

Comment: Moving to Stack Overflow; this isn't specifically game developemnt related. Hope you find an answer there!